# Why would avoiding sitting still for long periods help prevent tendinitis?

Tags: tendinopathy

The webpage [Can Bursitis and Tendinitis Be Prevented?](http://www.niams.nih.gov/Health_Info/Bursitis/) says:

> To help prevent inflammation or reduce the severity of its recurrence:
>
> - Begin new activities or exercise regimens slowly.
> - Gradually increase physical demands following several well-tolerated exercise sessions.
> - Exercise regularly.
> - Strengthen muscles around the joint.
> - Take breaks from repetitive tasks often.
> - Stop activities that cause pain.
> - Cushion the affected joint. Use foam for kneeling or elbow pads. Increase the gripping surface of tools with gloves or padding. Apply
>     grip tape or an oversized grip to golf clubs.
> - Use two hands to hold heavy tools; use a two-handed backhand in tennis.
> - **Don’t sit still for long periods.**
> - Practice good posture and position the body properly when going about daily activities.
> - If a history of tendinitis is present, consider seeking guidance from your doctor or therapist before engaging in new exercises and
>     activities.

Why would avoiding sitting still for long periods help prevent tendinitis?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.